# Filling the Gaps on Verilog/System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I went over a few Verilog tutorials and reviewed the topics a couple times and a few questions have been lingering in my head from since the concepts were first introduced and if anyone could shed them light on them, that would be very helpful.

1. What's the purpose of strength on a net?
2. Often times in examples parameters exact names are used to also describe registers.  For example:

   ```
   module x (…,in1,…);
   …
   input in1;
   reg [7:0] in1; 
   …
   endmodule
   ```

   Does this declare the input port as a type of data or are they separate? If the former is true, what other kinds of quantities can I do this with (integers, scalars, etc.)? If the latter is true which item am I referring to when I say “in1” inside the module?
3. Initial blocks at the beginning of a simulation all get executed in “parallel” but when you’re inside the block, the instructions are executed serially. Does the simulation tool you’re using determine what order the serially executed instructions are done in? For instance you have 2 initial blocks, do we execute all of one first, or jump back and forth?

4 .Why are initial values in simulation X? If Verilog’s job is to represent real life why doesn’t it have a pseudo random engine and pick the same random order of bits for all the values at the beginning? You run into a lot of issues with unique case statement warnings and it seems like a design flaw or at least an incongruity between system Verilog and Verilog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lets you have multiple drivers on a net and determine the value of the resulting signal; see 7.10 in the LRM
2. They're all the same `in1` - very verbose. In V-2001 you can write a single `input reg[7:0] in1` in the port list instead. You can do this for anything that you connect through a port.
3. Note that initial's are not guaranteed to be executed before always, and there is no guaranteed order of execution between any initial/always blocks in your design. In practice, the simulator chooses a block, and executes it until it reaches a suspend point (a timing control), at which point the sim schedules another initial or always, and executes that until it suspends, and so on.
4. This is essentially philosphy, but why would you want to assign initial random values to anything? This is basically what 'unknown' (X) means (or Z for nets). If everything is X or Z at the beginning of time, then you know that it's uninitialised and will remain so until you do something to it. If the tool gave everything initial random valid values you'd never know that.

Comment: If everything had an initial randomized value, you wouldn't get numerous run time warnings regarding not having a matching case for your unique case blocks because the values you're testing are unknown. . I'll check out that LRM, thanks!

Comment: You could look up casex/casez for matching unknowns, or hold off the case testing till everything is initialised, or ignore time-0 warnings - just giving everything a non-x default wouldn't be a good idea. Apart from anything else, your sims wouldn't be repeatable.

Comment: 7.10 of the LRM is labeled "Queues." Is this the section you had intended for me to read? The way I avoid the unique case runtime warning issue is by compiling with "-xlrm uniq_prior_final" which holds off checking unique case statements until the end of the time step. Works well, I was just curious if they had to implement this switches because of incongruity between the the two languages.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter EML is referring to section 7.10 of IEEE1364-2001 . In IEEE Std 1800-2012 ( FREE @ http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf ) then it is sections 28.10 through 28.15 (lot of detail and examples).

Comment: Initial block is not used for modeling a real hardware, which is a synthesizable design. Designers shall always use sensitivity list and monitor reset or some special signals to reset the hardware status, not use statements in the initial block. Initial block shall be used for some preparation of simulation environment or testbench, but not real design modeling itself.

Comment: If the value is randomly determined, it would be at least 0 or 1 exactly. However, in real world, transistor is an analog device, you cannot tell its value is 0 or 1 by its voltage sometimes when it does not close to GND or VDD within a threshold. Such that it needs unknown value to define its state.

Answer (score 0):

1. In case of a contention strength helps to resolve to a known value.  Last time I saw something like this in a design was it 10 years ago.  And even then it was considered to be a bad design practice.
2. As EML says it.
3. No and No.  The statements in any procedural block such as initial block are executed sequentially within the same time-slot.  The initial blocks begin execution at time 0.  The simulator executes all the statements in the order they appear inside the initial block as per the verilog event queue.  The variables are updated as per the schedule dictated by the event queue.  All of this is part of the standard (LRM 8.10).   If you are not familiar with verilog event queue and the notion of time-slots and simulation time then [Cliff Cumming's paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events.pdf) is a great reference.  It doesn't matter if the simulator executes the statements from different initial blocks interleaved or any other way.  The simulation time doesn't advance and the variables are only updated based on the event queue.

   What is not standard is which initial block the simulator should begin with. This becomes important because this creates dependency on the simulator if variables are assigned in one initial block and used in the other procedural block within the same event queue.  Cumming's paper referenced above explains this scenario very nicely.
4. It's not just about the unresolved state of the net.  But also about starting the simulation from a predictable state.  Therefore, randomly picking the resolved state of the inputs to the design would not provide the predictability in starting the simulator from the same point everytime.  In addition to EML's suggestion, you may use the 2-state datatypes provided in SystemVerilog.  Ofcourse, these are not synthesizable.  Because, to accurately model the hardware you want the output state to be unknown if the inputs are unknown.